# How do I apply parallax on middle of webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, parallax

I want apply parallax scrolling effect on middle of my page but when scrolling and reaching to middle of page it already gets messed up

I even tried to use intersection observer but it doesn't work

```
const section = document.querySelector(".parallax");
const img = document.querySelectorAll("img");
const title = document.querySelector(".title")
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) =>{
    entries.forEach((entry) =>{
        if(entry.isIntersecting){
            window.addEventListener("scroll", ()=>{
                console.log(window.scrollY);
                img[0].style.top = `-${window.scrollY/12}px`;
                img[1].style.top = `-${window.scrollY /13}px`;
                img[2].style.top = `-${window.scrollY / 14}px`;
                img[3].style.top = `-${window.scrollY / 15}px`;
                img[4].style.top = `-${window.scrollY / 16}px`;
                img[5].style.top = `-${window.scrollY / 17}px`;
                img[6].style.top = `-${window.scrollY / 18}px`;
                title.style.marginRight = `${window.scrollY}px`;
            })
        }
    })
}, {
    threshold:0
})

observer.observe(section);
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS too please.

Answer (score 0):

There's a post by [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp) on this topic.

Here is a very simple snippet showing what you would need to do to achieve this:

```css
.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-logos-6/512/121-css3-512.png");

  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 500px; 

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.</p>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<div style="height:1000px;background-color:lightblue;font-size:36px">
The image stays in place!
</div>

</body>
</html>
```